# Why does Jest error without try/catch blocks for async test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm learning Jest and when I run this first example I get an error when running the test. If I wrap it in a try/catch block it works fine. The docs show examples without try/catch. Why is the first example error?

**ERRORS**

```
  test('controller type error is correct', async () => {
    expect(await pipe('string', podchain)).toThrow('VALIDATE PROPS: podchain must be an object.')
  })
```

**DOES NOT ERROR**

```
  test('controller type error is correct', async () => {
    try {
      expect(await pipe('string', podchain)).toThrow('VALIDATE PROPS: podchain must be an object.')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.toThrow()` expectation is supposed to work on a function, and `await pipe('string', podchain))` isn't a function that throws. In a normal async function, try-catch blocks are re-written to be `.catch()` terms on the end of promises, but in jest that re-write doesn't work.

I suggest using the Jest `.rejects` helper:

```
await expect(pipe('string', podchain)).rejects.toThrow();
```

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects

Comment: This solved the problem. I still don't quite understand why the try/catch worked but thank you anyways.